# Liquid Crystal LCD Programming with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, i2c, lcd

I would like my LCD to display "Voltage=(sensorValue)" but right now the only way I can get the program to recognize the value as I turn the potentiometer is if I put it in a loop. But when I put it in a loop the whole screen gets filled with 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, or 5s depending on where the potentiometer is set.

If I don't have it in a loop then whatever setting the potentiometer is on is what will pop on the screen and will not change if potentiometer is turned.

How can I put the results of a loop outside of a loop so I can have "(Voltage=sensoreValue)"?

Here's my program:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  

void setup()
{
    lcd.init();                      
    lcd.backlight();
    int sensorPin = A0;
    int sensorValue = 0;
    sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
    lcd.print("Voltage=");
}

void loop()
{
    int sensorPin = A0;
    int sensorValue = 0;
    sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
    lcd.print(sensorValue);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LCD Programming with Arduino](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220673/lcd-programming-with-arduino)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with last week.  Thanks for all the advice guys!

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  

void setup() {}

void loop()
{ lcd.init();                      
lcd.backlight();

int VoltsInput = A0;
int VoltsRange = 0;
int VoltsPercent = 0;

VoltsRange = (5.0/1023.0) * analogRead(VoltsInput);
VoltsPercent = (((5.0/1023.0) * analogRead(VoltsInput)) / 5) * 100;

lcd.print(VoltsRange);
lcd.print("V    ");

lcd.print(VoltsPercent);
lcd.print("%");}
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the loop() and use a delay() function, so that your program reads the value from pot every few seconds instead of every millisecond.

Comment: Thanks, Sudar!  I think I may have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `print()` is clearing the screen of previous data every time it is called (although the relevant documentation and library code available [here](http://hmario.home.xs4all.nl/arduino/LiquidCrystal_I2C/) and [here](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/LCDAPI) is unclear).

If this is the case you need to print the `Voltage=` string in the loop along with the sensor value. Try changing your code to:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  
int sensorPin = A0;

void setup()
{
    lcd.init();                      
    lcd.backlight();
}

void loop()
{
    int sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
    String display = "Voltage=";
    display += sensorValue;
    lcd.print(display);
}
```