# LCD Programming with Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I would like my LCD to display "Voltage=(sensorValue)" but right now the only way I can get the program to recognize the value as I turn the potentiometer is if I put it in a loop. But when I put it in a loop the whole screen gets filled with 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, or 5s depending on where the potentiometer is set.

If I don't have it in a loop then whatever setting the potentiometer is on is what will pop on the screen and will not change if potentiometer is turned.

How can I put the results of a loop outside of a loop so I can have "(Voltage=sensoreValue)"?

Here's my program:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  

void setup()
{
    lcd.init();                      
    lcd.backlight();
    int sensorPin = A0;
    int sensorValue = 0;
    sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
    lcd.print("Voltage=");
}

void loop()
{
    int sensorPin = A0;
    int sensorValue = 0;
    sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
    lcd.print(sensorValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked it to print the reading and it is doing - it's printing each reading!

I suspect you either want it to only print if the value changes

```
int sensorValue = 0;
int prevValue = 0;

void loop()
{    
    sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
    if (sensorValue != prevValue) {
       lcd.print(sensorValue);
       prevValue == sensorValue;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could print 'n' backspaces so the new value is printed over the top of the old one, if your display lcd.print supports that

Comment: Didn't know you had the arduino gene in you.

Comment: @karlphillip - Have done HW, I used to design and build those big Telescopes in Chile. Arduinos are great, I needed to detect a particular error bit pattern on a bus. From out of the box I had it working in less than the time it takes to install the compiler for most microprocessors.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `print()` is clearing the screen of previous data every time it is called (although the relevant documentation and library code available [here](http://hmario.home.xs4all.nl/arduino/LiquidCrystal_I2C/) and [here](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/LCDAPI) is unclear).

If this is the case you need to print the `Voltage=` string in the loop along with the sensor value. Try changing your code to:

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  
int sensorPin = A0;

void setup()
{
    lcd.init();                      
    lcd.backlight();
}

void loop()
{
    int sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
    String display = "Voltage=";
    display += sensorValue;
    lcd.print(display);
}
```